# email component smtp error cakephp

Tags: email, cakephp, components, smtp

im getting this error when sending emails with cake's email component

```
[smtpError] => 535 5.7.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 r11sm77490vbx.11
```

any ideas? here's my code...

```
 $this->Email->to = array(' juan <name@gmail.com>'); 
 $this->Email->from = 'name@gmail.com';
    $this->Email->subject = 'Welcome to our really cool thing';
    $this->Email->template = 'simple_message'; 

    $this->Email->sendAs = 'both'; 
  $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
        'port'=>'465', 
        'timeout'=>'30',
  'auth' => true,
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'username'=>'name@gmail.com',
        'password'=>'********',

   );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a space there before your name, which could possibly be sending the wrong data.  Have you tried the code without that extra space?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the link in the error message to google's support forums say that the username and password combination are incorrect.  I'd recommend that you try logging in to that gmail account with the specified password, just to triple check that you're not mistaken.  That happens a lot to me, all the time.

Secondly, are you sure you're supposed to put the @gmail.com in for the username?  Maybe it should just be 'name' rather than 'name@gmail.com'.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from that stated by @Travis ... i would also suggest that the from should also be constructed in this format "Name " ... otherwise I don't think the email will go through.